# iPad - Showing a custom UIViewController from a ShareKit sharer

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, sharekit

I have a custom sharer with ShareKit that redirects to an UIViewController of my application to do some actions. Normally I use this code to do that task on the iPhone

```
//Create a new snippet with the item to be shared
Snippet * selectedSnippet = [[Snippet alloc] initWith: item.title :item.text :@"" : 0];

//pass the item to the controller
detailsController.currentSnippet = selectedSnippet;

//Show view controller with the navigation controller
[[SHK currentHelper] showViewController: detailsController];
```

But this shows my `UIViewController` cropped, my guess is because it's being shown as a modal window, so I also tried:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: detailsController animated: YES];
```

Instead of the last line and no luck. What I want is to show an `UIViewController` from my sharer but using the whole screen for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `[SHK currentHelper]`. For inspiration, look at how SHKiOS5Twitter presents its UI in [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/)

Here are the steps:

1. check if there is no ShareKit's menu, or other ShareKit's view opened. If it is, close it and continue after close notification.
2. find current top view controller, [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/) has a special function for this.
3. then simply use UIView's presentViewController:animated:completion: method